# Polymer 1.x: Help getting this JSBin to render <paper-header-panel> and <paper-toolbar>

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

http://jsbin.com/mefonoqanu/1/edit?html,output

[This JSBin doesn't render its contents](http://jsbin.com/mefonoqanu/1/edit?html,output). It does not display:

- its ***header*** section — the `<paper-toolbar>` text (i.e., `"Header"`) or
- its ***content panel*** section — the `<div>` element (i.e., `"Content goes here..."`).

> **What am I doing wrong?** Please provide a working JSBin example.

**Note:** [Per this link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel), `<paper-header-panel>` requires host to have a `height`.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<x-element></x-element>
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
      <paper-toolbar>Header</paper-toolbar>
      <div>Content goes here...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>   
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/kabede/5/edit?html,output

The changes:

1. webcomponents from rawgit instead of bower_components
2. `<span class="title">` to make header visible
3. style="width:100%; height: 100%;" on element to see its content

Comment: 1. is not necessary. 2. is necessary. 3. is half necessary. `<paper-header-panel>` needs a `height` in order to render properly. [See this link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel). We can use the `:host` selector to set the height in CSS. http://jsbin.com/bamiciyofu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Code of accepted answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">

</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<x-element style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></x-element>
  <dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
      <paper-toolbar ><span class="title">Header</span></paper-toolbar>
      <div >
        Content goes here...<br>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>   
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the minimum markup necessary to answer the question](http://jsbin.com/jocinasovo/edit?html,output):

http://jsbin.com/jocinasovo/edit?html,output

#### Changes

1. Added style using `:host`
2. Only need `height` not `width`
3. No need to switch from `bower_components` ([per this link](http://element-party.xyz)) to `rawgit` CDN
4. No need for `.flex` class on `<paper-header-panel>`

**Note:** [Per this link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel), `<paper-header-panel>` requires host to have a `height`.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<x-element></x-element>
  <dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        height: 100%
      }
    </style>
    <paper-header-panel>
      <paper-toolbar><span>Header</span></paper-toolbar>
      <div>Content goes here...</div>
    </paper-header-panel>   
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```